# Migration error - Unable to Load Site Preferences; Invalid Preference Data

Tags: expressionengine

I'm moving an EE upgrade from local to production server and and getting the dreaded "Unable to Load Site Preferences; Invalid Preference Data" error.

I've tripled checked everything. DB connection is fine, paths are set correctly, DB table has site preferences etc... What else should I check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When updating from EE1 to EE2, this error message will also appear if you migrated all the files and DB to the new server, but you **forgot to replace the main `index.php` file** in your site's root. So, be sure that file is the EE2 version as well.

Comment: Very good to know! Filing this as I'm sure it will happen to me. I can't believe I got stuck by uploading the wrong DB. Noob.

Answer (score 5):

If you get the "Unable to Load Site Preferences; Invalid Preference Data" error after migrating a site, make sure to check that you imported the correct EE2 database instead of the wrong EE1 database. If it's correct you'll see a exp_channel_data table.

Comment: good catch. just had this happen and I couldn't figure out where things went wrong.